# Getting DoReferenceTransaction Errors - Error 11458

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

We have to integrate "Paypal Reference Transaction" for the regular customers using sandbox account.

Currently allowed options are

1. Credit Card via Paypal
2. Pay by PayPal.

   So, whevever there is a transaction on any of the above, we capture the Transaction ID & this would be used to do the "Reference Transction" for the next time. In this case, customer is not required to provide their CC details again.

   This Reference Transaction works fine for all the CC payment transations. But not for the "Pay by PayPal" options. We are getting the following error while we try to do the "Reference Transation".

Error: Credit card details section must be empty; you cannot specify credit card information in a non-direct payment (DCC) reference transaction.

Please help on this to fix this issue ?.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you are passing over in your API request?

Comment: Below is the code:                                                                                                                           $nvpStr="&REFERENCEID=$referenceid&PAYMENTACTION=Sale&AMT=$amount&CURRENCYCODE=$currency&FIRSTNAME=$firstname&LASTNAME=$lastname"; 
                                                                    $nvpreq = "METHOD=$methodName_&VERSION=$version&PWD=$API_Password&USER=$API_UserName&SIGNATURE=$API_Signature$nvpStr";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvpreq);

Answer (score 1):

Remove the "FIRSTNAME", "LASTNAME" and "EMAIL" section from your API request.